# Korean place names romanisation in R

Tags: r, korea

What R resources are there to romanise Korean place names? The places in question are administrative areas, from regions down to city districts.

It could take the form of a gazetteer listing place names in both *hangul* and Roman scripts or it could take the form of a *hangul* to Roman converter.

Comment: Have you tried either [`stri_trans_general`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/stringi/html/stri_trans_general.html) or [`stringi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html)?

Comment: @Taras `stri_trans_general` goes some of the way but does not seem to provide the official [Revised Romanization of Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Romanization_of_Korean), e.g. "종로구 사직동" converts to "jongLogu sajiGdong" instead of "jongNogu sajiKdong."

Comment: I think you'll get more accurate answers on Stackoverflow and I don't see a GIS problem here.

Comment: @J._Monticolo The question may not be entirely solvable algorithmically, in case some official romanisations are customary/irregular, hence the suggestion of a gazetteer.